# Function of a sequence of Numbers

Tags: functions

Given $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ as a sequence of real numbers, define
$\{c_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ Such that for each $j \in \{1,2,3,...\},$ We know
that
$$c_j = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{j} a_i}{j}.$$
I want to show that if $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} a_j = q,$ then
$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} c_j = q.$ That being said, I am not sure about
the tools I have available to go about solving this problem. I do know that
$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0,$ $|a_j-q|
< \epsilon$ for $j > N.$ I would like to go about using this knowledge to
bound $|m_j - q|$ with a function of $\epsilon.$

Comment: Is this a duplicate? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Also known as the Cesaro mean.